# Symfony form puts the first entity when null returned

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-forms

I have two entities, with One To One relation, as following

```
    class Human {
          /**
           * @var Merit
           * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Merit", mappedBy="human")
           */
           private $merit;
    }

    class Merit {
          /**
           * @var Human
           * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Human", inversedBy="merit")
           * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="human_id", referencedColumnName="id")
           */
           private $human;
    }
```

I want them to be optional, so Human may not have a merit and vice versa, a merit can be without human.
when I make a form for human entity like this:

```
           ->add('merit', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => Entity\Merit::class,
                'choice_label' => 'id',
                'disabled' => true,
            ])
```

All is ok. But if the Human has not got a merit, then I **ALWAYS** have  my form with "pre-defined" merit with ID = 1. Why is that?

Comment: I managed to achieve what I wanted with `'placeholder'` option